# ODE - Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, transfer-theory

Tried solving those for the past few days and could not get far enough to find the answers anyone can help with those?

Using the Laplace transform, find the the solution $y(t)$ of the ODE

$$2y''(t)+20y'(t)+32y(t)=2u(t)$$

where  $y'(0)=0$, $y(0)=1$, and $u(t)$ is the unit step function.

Expected solution: $$y(t) = 0.0625 + 1.25e^{-2t} - 0.3125e^{-8t}.$$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The procedure is as follows: compute the Laplace transform of both sides of the equation, solve for $Y(s)$, express $Y(s)$ is terms of simple fractions, use the inverse Laplace transform to get the solution $y(t)$.

Comment: It feels like I don't have the math level to find the answer. I'm having trouble solving for Y(s). I might need to go back to calculus before doing this but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You have tables for the Laplace transform and its inverse. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: i'll try this ig

Answer (score 2):

We want to solve the IVP
$$2y''(t)+20y'(t)+32y(t)=2H(t)$$
with conditions $y'(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$ using Laplace transformations.

Begin by removing the factor of $2$ and taking the Laplace transform to get
\begin{align*}
\mathcal L\{y''(t)\}(s)+10\mathcal L\{y'(t)\}(s)+16\mathcal L\{y(t)\}(s)&=\mathcal L\{H(t)\}(s)\\
\left[s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)\right]+10\left[sY(s)-y(0)\right]+16[Y(s)]&=\frac1s\\
s^2Y(s)-s+10sY(s)-10+16Y(s)&=\frac1s\\
\left(s^2+10s+16\right)Y(s)&=\frac1s+s+10\\
Y(s)&=\frac{s^2+10s+1}{s(s+8)(s+2)}
\end{align*}
Upon this result we can perform PFD to get
$$Y(s)=\frac{s^2+10s+1}{s(s+8)(s+2)}=\frac1{16s}+\frac5{4(2+s)}-\frac5{16(8+s)}$$
Now, take the inverse Laplace transform to get
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}&=\frac1{16}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac1{s}\right\}+\frac{5}{4}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac1{2+s}\right\}-\frac5{16}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac1{8+s}\right\}\\
y(t)&=\boxed{\frac1{16}+\frac5{4}e^{-2t}-\frac{5}{16}e^{-8t}}
\end{align*}

Comment: I think you have a couple of errors going from the second to the third line of your solution.

Comment: @JohnBarber ok its now fixed lol was in class when i wrote this so did not pay too much attention oops